# String passed to Angular2 Component is always undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

When I'm passing a string to an @Input() of the Component, it is always undefined.

This is where I loop trough my array and pass the string to the component

https://github.com/davidhoeck/ng2-realtime-chat/blob/master/src/client/app/%2Bmessaging-page/messaging-page.component.html

And thats my component where I'm trying to get the value from the string passed trough.

https://github.com/davidhoeck/ng2-realtime-chat/blob/master/src/client/app/chat-window-component/chat-window-component.component.ts

Would be great if somebody could solve my problem.

Comment: hey David. Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the how to ask a good question guide found here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It will help you get better answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are sending the string. **"default"** gets evaluated as a variable, and since it's not present in the controller it will evaluate to **undefined**.

Instead add use single quotes to denote a string in a template.

```
<chat-window [groupid]="'default'"></chat-window>
```

You can see the issue in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/xHAWR0vyr9jMMyiq0aAr?p=preview) small plunker example.

Comment: Hmm, i also does not work. I also checked if the group ID is null, but even if the group id has value I get an undefined.

Comment: Indeed that was not the issue, at least not with the default value you were sending.